# GCP, can I use compute engine metadatas within cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I want to use compute engine metadatas as environment variables within cloud function.

Is that possible?

Within cloud function, use like this:

```
const { apiKey } = process.env;

exports.createBook = () => {/*...*/}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** I don't think my answer below is correct. I am told there's metadata server accessible on GCF and Google App Engine. Please consider accepting another answer that explain this better.

---

*Google Cloud Functions don't run on Google Compute Engine, so you won't be able to access the Compute Metadata service within GCF functions.
Your code snippet doesn't illustrate how is it related to Compute Engine metadata server, but I'm assuming you want to read some environment variables from the metadata server.
Set environment variables at the deployment-time instead: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var*